# How to make linaria work with turbo repo and next js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, linaria, turborepo

To set up linaria with next js we can use `next-linaria` package as shown in `with-linaria` example. Setting up next js for linaria, we can do `npx create-next-app -e with-linaria`. However, I get trouble in adding linaria to the ui package in a turbo repo monorepo.

Following is directory structure of scaffold by `npx create-turbo`

```
- apps
  - admin
  - web
- packages
  - ui
```

I want to use linaria for ui component as well.